# Unwanted comma-separated arguments to Spring controller method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm seeing a strange problem with a Spring MVC controller.  This method is intended to set the password.  It takes two form parameters "password" and "confirmPassword".  The first time the form is called, this works fine-- the fields are passed to the method.

The problem occurs when the form is submitted a second time.  If the form is incorrectly filled out the first time, the user is correctly sent back to the form page and prompted to enter the password again.  However the arguments to the method are incorrect on the second try.  The arguments are a comma separated list which includes the first form entry concatenated with the second.

Example:

First form post with field "password" has a value of "abc".  Method argument "password" has value "abc".

Second form post with field "password" and a value of "xyz".  Method argument "password" has value "xyz,abc".

The Spring MVC docs don't indicate much useful.  Somehow the old form post is remembered and included. Anyone have experience in solving this?

Controller method is below:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/account/reset", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String resetPassword(@RequestParam("password") String password,
        @RequestParam("confirmPassword") String confirmPassword,
        @RequestParam("hash") String hash, ModelMap model) throws EncryptionException
{
    String userName = stringEncrypterService.decrypt(hash);
    User user = userService.findUserByPath(userName);

    if (!password.equals(confirmPassword))
    {
        model.put("hash", hash);
        model.put("user", user);
        model.put("error",
                "The two passwords you entered below do not match. Please try again.");

        return "users/resetPassword";
    }

    userService.updatePassword(user, password);
    emailService.sendUserInfoChange(user);
    return "redirect:/session/signin?passwordReset=true";
}
```

Update.  Several responders have suggested that perhaps the problematic posts have extra URL parameters or hidden form fields resulting in duplicate field names.  I confirmed with Fiddler that this is not the case.  Here's the raw request from the third try. (slightly edited to remove session cookie).

```
POST http://wintest.foriodev.com/simulate/account/reset/ HTTP/1.1
Host: wintest.foriodev.com
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://wintest.foriodev.com/simulate/account/reset/
Content-Length: 73
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: http://wintest.foriodev.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.16 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/10.0.648.133 Safari/534.16
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: AUTOLOGIN_TOKEN=xyz; SIMULATE_WORKER=wintest; JSESSIONID=xyz; 

password=a&hash=xyz&confirmPassword=a&save=Reset+Password
```

Comment: Seems like a session issue. Did you set the page session to false in your JSP ?

Comment: can you post the relevant parts of your jsp?

Comment: The trick is to make a better UrlViewResolver. See my answer. The one that Spring provides has that dumb default behavior.

Comment: interesting.  I see somebody has posted a bounty on this old question and it suddenly has new life.  I will review these responses and test them.

Comment: @WillGlass I'm absolutely sure the problem you had has to do with the RedirectView adding model attributes as parameters. I have contemplated filing a bug with Spring adding better documentation or making it easier to disable this.

Comment: Adam - that's not the problem.  The issue occurs when the passwords do not match.  That returns the result "users/resetPassword".  The returned value for the redirect is never hit.  I verified this by stepping through the code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So after more than a year I figured this out.

The problem was a custom interceptor that stored the request cache on each request.  I do this so that when a user logs on, he will go back to the previous screen.  But it's completely inappropriate for a "reset password" screen.

The mechanism was that when request.getParameter(Name) is called the SavedRequestCacheWrapper would then concatenate the actual HTTP request parameters with the stored parameters from that last request.

The solution is to (a) have this interceptor ignore the reset password screen and (b) ignore all post requests to prevent this kind of request parameter value concatenation.

To the other responders, thanks for all the good ideas.  (And to the anonymous user who put a bounty on this - thanks for causing me to go back and take another look.)

Comment: not that I get the bounty since it's my own question.  :-)  But the increased attention made me look at it again.

Comment: I wonder which issue the bounty user had. I too have had some issues with the `SavedRequest*` (particularly with OAuth Facebook).

Answer (score 8):

I think the reason for this is because of

return "**redirect:**/session/signin?passwordReset=true";

With redirect: the framework uses the url-rewriting technique, similar to the basic response.sendRedirect(...) in servlets, and hence the parameter,values are appended along with the request to the next consequent requests and so on.

Try using a different mechanism rather than "**redirect:**"

Comment: Yeah, the redirect would result in the user input getting put into the URL as query parameters. You should only do the "redirect:" in the case of a successful form post. If there are errors with the data provided by the user you should send them to the form again WITHOUT a redirect.

Comment: @user960587 He *can* use the same mechanism that `"redirect:"` does (UrlViewResolver) he just has to customize it so that `"redirect:"` doesn't do that. See my answer.

Comment: The redirect is never hit.  It's hit upon success, but this problem occurs when the passwords don't match,

Answer (score 4):

If you post a third time, does the list grow to three, too? This would indicate that the problem is related to the user's session. Or, if the list stays at two, then the problem is in the request. I'm guessing that the list grows to three, since the info you posted from Fiddler shows no sign of duplication in the request.

To confirm the data is in the session, check its contents (ex. print to a log, use a debugger, print to the web page in a dev environment) for data under the same keys -- "password", "hash", etc.

Also, see [this other response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503683/requestparam-variables-return-a-set-of-comma-separated-values-when-a-method-get) about why data might be in the user's session, ex. you used the @SessionAttributes annotation somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

You will get comma seperated values when you have multiple form fields that have the same name.  A common cause for this is to have hidden inputs and text inputs with the same name.  The first time the page posts, the hidden inputs will be empty so, no commas.  The second (and subsiquent) time the page posts, the hidden inputs will have values, so you get commas.

Comment: when you have for-each loop , we cannot avoid commas. Any idea on how to resolve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45352952/hidden-class-creates-commas-in-spring-webflow

Comment: @MR AND the for-each loop in no way forces you to use the same name for each element in the for-each loop.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the old values somehow appear as GET parameters, i.e. either you have `<form action = ".../account/reset?password=abc">` in the second form, or `action` is empty and URL of the second form itself is `.../account/reset?password=abc`. Though I can't find anything responsible for it in your code.

Comment: the values do not appear as get parameters.  I verified there's no redirect with chrome dev tools, and I don't see them on the url

Answer (score 0):

Are you somehow specify the form fields a second time when you come back from the validation step? Use Firebug or something similar to inspect what you're sending and/or post your jsp (or similar) page.

Comment: I have reviewed my posts with Fiddler and confirmed they are as entered by the user-- no comma separated values.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this might be caused by the issue https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1258
"SavedRequestAwareWrapper causes trouble in 3.0 M2 in combination with Spring MVC"

Comment: I'm using version 3.0.5 but the issue reports that was fixed in 3.0.0 RC1

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had associated hidden field with a path that was unused. Removing the hidden field helped me resolve the issue.