# @RequestParam variables return a set of comma separated values, when a method gets called several times

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I just noticed that a @RequestParam variable that I use to check POST params, such as usernames, or ids, behaves rather strangely when the controller method gets called consecutive times. Rather than returning the current parameter value (for example, "Jason", "Michael", "John"), it returns a concatenated string of all parameter values that the method has been called with before that. It results in the variable having the value of: "Jason,Michael,John", rather than just "John" which was the last one.

I noticed that this strange behavior is per session. When I reduced the session duration to 1 minute only, i noticed that after the session is gone, so are the multiple values.

This thing never happens if I call request.getParameter("username"). Of course, I would like to stick to Spring MVC conventions if possible.

Is this a bug, or something intentional? How can I avoid it?

Comment: could you share your page from where you submit the request. will help analyzing.

Comment: please add the code of your controller class

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug in your JSP page.  You likely have a hidden and an input with the same name.  This results in a comma separated list of values.

Comment: That wouldn't necessarily explain why the values keep being concatenated more and more with each call. An input and hidden with the same name would at most just return 2 (or at any rate a fixed number of) values

Comment: it exactly explains why the values keep getting concatenated.  the value in the hidden concats with the value in the input.  then repeat.  However, this is not guaranteed to be the cause of this question.

Comment: Yes I agree with the first 2 sentences of your comment. But how exactlly would a multi valued parameter trigger the repeat part all by itself? And besides the OP sais that by reducing his servlet session timeout it seems to clear the issue - so I think it's a lot more likely that it's something related to that.

Comment: 1. hidden has no value, input gets value; no comma separated value string.  2. hidden is populated with the value submitted from the input when page repaints.  3. input gets new value, hidden has the old value.  on submit you get a comma separated value string since the input and the hidden have the same name.  4. repeat 2 and 3.

Comment: Dude:"I noticed that this strange behavior is per session. When I reduced the session duration to 1 minute only, i noticed that after the session is gone, so are the multiple values."

Comment: That may be a red herring.  Without the code of the handler and the jsp we don't know if the hidden is populated from a session scoped value.  user802232, add some details please.

Comment: Then why does the multi value go away with the session, if it would be kept only in request scope?

Comment: No.  you assume that the value is in request scope.  it is common for junior programmers to store stuff in session that would better be stored in request scope.  Again, user802232, add some details.

Comment: No, YOU assume the value is stored in request scope only, I've actually said right from the start that it's probablly stored in session, look at my previous commets and answer

Comment: @DwB impossible. I checked the request dump, and there is not a single trace of a hidden field. I might agree more with the session scope stuff, although I do not see anything in my configuration file that suggests so. Could it be that session scope is by default? Perhaps I should turn the scope of my controller into "per-request" explicitly

Comment: check the html of the page, not the request.  a hidden field will look like this: <input type="hidden" .../>

Answer (score 1):

Try without spring annotations:

Add to your method an attribute named `HttpServletRequest`

```
String s = request.getParameter("parameterName")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your attribute might be saved internally by spring in the http session and re-used from there. Do you by any chance, on you spring controller class, have a configuration that would make that parameter session scoped (Either `@SessionAttributes("username")` on the class, or requireSession=true in your xml declaration of the controller bean)?

Or do you'add it to the model when you rediplay your page from the controller?

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue while implementing an ajax login and found out that it was caused by the redirect that is triggered after the failing attempts to login. Somehow was accumulating the j_usernamen and j_password parameters.