# Hidden class creates commas in spring webflow

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I am displaying a list of items using spring webflow.
Each item has an edit button; clicking the button opens up a modal dialog.
If there are 12 items in the list,
I see 12 commas generated in the form path.
How can I avoid generation of commas?

```
<c:forEach var="note" items="${model.modelname}">
//create a click button for each item
//each click opens up a modal

    <div id="modal" class="hidden">
        <div class="modal-body-content">
            <form:textarea path="textPath" />
        </div>
    </div>  

</c:forEach>
```

Comment: please, provide data sample, maybe a screenshot, configuration to reproduce an issue

Comment: model.modelname is a list and textPath is a string in this case.

Comment: it's not enough to make any assumptions, the issue seems to be somewhere else. Provide configuration, maybe even project - I could take a look now

Comment: class hidden should contain the following css {display:none;}

Comment: @Cassian I tried to add the display attribute as <div id="modal" class="hidden" style="display: none"> but did not find any difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that in a single form, you have multiple `textarea` fields with the exact same field name ("textPath") (and exact same DOM ID, which isn't good either).

If so, I'm not surprised that Spring combines all the values submitted under that single name, with commas separating them. What Java type is your model bean's `textPath` field? I think if it were an array or maybe `List`, you might get the values separated out. But that's just a guess.

Comment: data type for the text path is a string.

Comment: Yes, that's probably why it's being comma-separated. If you're sending multiple parameters with that exact same name, I think they're being combined into a single string with commas separating each value. If you want no commas, you need to either use different names for each field, of make the data element's type an Array, then I think each element will get one of the parameters.

Comment: Problem is I have all the list in model.modelname and in the text path all I am trying to do is retrieve each of them. I don't think helps if i try to use list or array.

Comment: Seems like the way to resolve this issue is by disabling text area when class is hidden

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues at work.
As noted by @dbreaux,
all of your textarea elements are in the same form and have the same id;
this is causing the commas when you post the form.

1. The element id is supposed to be unique to each element.  Your element id is "modal" is not unique.  Make it unique.  This is not causing the commas.
2. The name of each textarea is textPath.  Since you have multiple elements with one name, you get a comma separated list of values for that element name when you post the form.  Each textarea must have a unique name.  It appears that you have a unique name for each modal (the loop variable is the modalName).  Use that in the name of the textarea.
3. If you can't give each textarea a unique name, give each textarea its own form.  Generate a new form for each modal div.

Here is an example of the solution I proposed in #2 above (Note: I don't have a system running that uses spring tags ATM, this example is untested):

```
<c:forEach var="note" items="${model.modelname}">
    <div id="modal" class="hidden">
        <div class="modal-body-content">
            <form:textarea path="${note}textPath" />
        </div>
    </div>  
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: I think the path should match to the variable in the pojo class. If we set path as ${note}textPath I don't think that will work. In addition to it the number of form can differ depending upon the list of item I have in database, so giving unique name is not possible.

Comment: @MR AND, Try a different excuse.  Giving a unique name is always possible.  If nothing else, you can include an index value in the model object that uniquely identifies each Modal dialog.

Comment: Or make it an array :-)